# How to automatically tag all samples in folder (Maschine)?

Tags: samples, tools, file-naming, tagging

Is there a way to automatically tag all samples in a particular folder?

For example, I have a folder in my samples directory full of vocals, and I want to tag them all with type "Vocal" and subtype "Male".

Is there any way to do this without locating each sample individually?

(I did that for one folder. It took almost an hour...)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know if Maschine keeps its own database of tags which then relate to the files? Or does it store tags in the file metadata? I did a quick search without coming up with an answer.

If it's the former (separate tag database), you may be able to edit the database file directly. If it's the latter (tags stored as metadata), then you should be able to use something like Adobe Bridge (or another metadata editor) to batch tag the files.

P.S. I realize that this is an old question, but I saw it in the unanswered queue and couldn't resist!

Comment: @ZeroFlux Don't worry; Necromancy is encouraged on the Stack Exchange network. There's even badges for it.